# C++ - where are the implementations of _List_node_base's member functions in the std::list headers

Tags: c++, stl

I'm perusing the source files of C++ STL in Ubuntu 14.04 x86. At the `std::list::_M_insert` which calls `_M_hook` of a `_List_node_base` object, I just can't find `_M_hook`'s definition. I tried to `grep` the entire /usr/include and `g++ -E` to process a source file that included `<list>` but got nothing interesting.

Maybe the implementation has been embedded into some binary thing like a lib file, since `struct _List_node_base` (defined at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:77) is not a template class. In fact not only `_M_hook` but also other members like `_M_reverse`, `_M_transfer`, I can't dig out their C++ sources either.

Wonder if I had missed something that contains the implementation. Or are they really precompiled into binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct; that method is indeed compiled into the library.  You can see the implementation in the git repo [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/list.cc;hb=6bbf0dec66c0e719b06cd2fe67559fda6df09000).

Answer (score 0):

They're defined in the `list.cc` file within libstdc++; it's in the `src/c++98` subdirectory there.

You can view `list.cc` at the main github mirror [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/list.cc). The definition for `_M_hook` is (currently) on line 126 there; you can view it [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/list.cc#L126).